# Why is boolean returning 0/1 in Jupyter Notebook Julia?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, boolean, julia

I have the following looking dataframe when calling in the Terminal:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(
    condition = [false, false, true, false, false, false, true, false, false, false],
    time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
```

Output:

```
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ condition  time  
     │ Bool       Int64 
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     false      1
   2 │     false      2
   3 │      true      3
   4 │     false      4
   5 │     false      5
   6 │     false      6
   7 │      true      7
   8 │     false      8
   9 │     false      9
  10 │     false     10
```

When I run the exact same code in a Jupyter Notebook with Julia the boolean is now 0/1 like this:

[image]

Why is this happening (because it has the same type `Bool`?) and is it possible to change this in the notebook to the same as in the terminal (true/false)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this.

I would classify it as a bug (we recently changed HTML printing backend and this issue was missed when doing migration). Please check [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/3265) where we will discuss what to do with it.

---

#### EDIT

We have investigated into the issue (and it seems I had the same issue on my machine).

The problem is that you do not have DataFrames.jl 1.4.x installed. You most likely have DataFrames.jl 1.3.x, which had this problem. The problem is currently fixed.

So the solution is that you should update your DataFrames.jl installation to 1.4 version and all will be consistent.

Comment: The issue is fixed. Please read my edit. Thank you!